# Emacs shortcuts for IDEA IDE?

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, intellij-idea

I'm just switching from Emacs to IDEA and it would be a great help to me if I could use shortcuts like Ctrl-A for jump-to-line-start. etc.
Is this possible?

Comment: @Łukasz Lew: The simple stuff are possible and there are also a few plugins allowing to have, say, a kill-ring and you can yank etc.  However that's not "the real thing".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A note from a long time Emacs and IDEA user - Emacs bindings in IDEA are simply mission impossible. Arthur is perfectly correct about how to enable them, but they will seriously tamper with your IDEA workflow since they tend to override a lot of default IDEA keybindings and in the end you have to come up with completely custom keymap. This is not a problem the first time - but when you have to work on some coworkers machines, or on other computers it becomes extremely annoying. I used to hold my keymap in Subversion.

So basically don't use the default Emacs keybinding in IDEA - copy the basic setup and extend it personally. The [IDEA server](http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/docs/DOC-1143) might be helpful to keep several computers in sync with the same keybindings.

Also keep in mind that only basic navigational commands are supported in IDEA and some helpful IDEA actions may wind up without keybindings by default so pay extra attention how you configure your IDEA.

For me there is only like place like Emacs - and that's Emacs. I have yet to see some software that provides sensible settings using Emacs keybindings.

Comment: The IntelliJ emacs bindings provided out of the box for c13 are perfectly usable and I haven't found them at all obstructive. Generally the keys you need the most are simple navigation, make, cut and paste types : easily and well done in the provided keymap.

Comment: @RichieHH  Yeah, it's a long time since the original answer, and things have improved a lot.

Comment: I wonder if there are any shortcoming with the current version of IntelliJ IDEA (2018.1.2) and its Emacs keymap.

Answer (score 28):

Go to Settings -> IDE Settings -> Keymap and you will have all the keymappsing.

One of the Keymaps you can select from is Emacs.

Comment: If you want to use the mark and be able to kill regions with it, you can install the "IntelliJ IDEA Mark Plugin".  I had to fiddle with the keybindings afterwards, but it works :)

Comment: @Martin: As of IntelliJ build 106.532 there is a new setting "Toggle Sticky Selection" which obviates the Mark Plugin (the plugin probably stopped working around version 10.5 of IntelliJ anyway), see http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-66719

Comment: As an extension to this answer, there is a plugin that extends emacs keymap with additional "obvious defaults" for any emacs user: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10045-emacs-patched.

By the way, why is this not an accepted answer? Bozhidar's answer is a great advice, but this is an accurate answer to the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

There's a useful article on this topic [here](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/08/07/intellij-emacs/).

The gist of what it says is

- You can tweak keybindings, but it's a bandaid at best, lost cause really
- You can do better by LivePlugin Scripting with Groovy
- You can create an escape hatch to emacs using emacsclient