# Intellij to use Emacs keymap

Tags: intellij-idea, emacs, keymapping

*Don't close it as a dup of [Emacs shortcuts for IDEA IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648342/emacs-shortcuts-for-idea-ide)
just yet without reading the whole question!*

I've done a lot of reading before opening this question --

- The ***selected*** answer from 2010 to [Emacs shortcuts for IDEA IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648342/emacs-shortcuts-for-idea-ide) begins with *"A note from a long time Emacs and IDEA user - Emacs bindings in IDEA are **simply mission impossible**"*, then followed with a short comment of *"things have improved a lot"* without any further explanation.
- There is an article [Customizing IntelliJ for Emacs Compatibility](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/08/07/intellij-emacs/) written in year 2014 begins with *"The biggest downside for me is its **poor Emacs compatibility out of the box**."* and ends up with doing his own Scripting with Groovy.

So what's the situation ***now***, almost 10 years later than the above two answers?
How to make Intellij to use Emacs keymap?

Comment: The problem description is too vague, and it would be impossible to answer this question. There is Emacs keymap in IntelliJ IDEA provided in the settings. The answer would be: switch to Emacs keymap in the IDE settings. But you would not accept it as you mentioned there are issues with this solution. The only way to address it would be to report the issues you face at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA so that they can be fixed (search for duplicates before reporting).

Comment: Hi @CrazyCoder, from the other Q&As that I read I know that you are a key contributor to IDEA, but this question might not be what you're thinking. Yes, the default Emacs keymap IntelliJ IDEA provided might not be enough, as I've read that people are using at least another plugin at the same time. However, I'm not trying to report any issues, but to ask people, being an Emacs user and trying to set Emacs & IDEA with same key mapping, how you are doing it? That's all I need, to get started in the right position, to make the best use of the current situation. That's all.